# Python and Mixins with Super

Tags: python, typeerror, mixins, init, super

I have the following class

```
from somewhere import ParentClass
from mixin_file import Mixin1 and Mixin2

class Test(Mixin1, Mixin2, ParentClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Test, self).__init__()
```

in mixin_file

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class Mixin1(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta
    @abstractmethod
    def do_something(self):
        pass

class Mixin2(object):
    def hello(self):
        pass
```

and when I run

```
x = Test()
```

the error

```
TypeError:__init__() takes exactly 0 arguments (2 given)
```

Do I need to pass the Mixin whens I initialize 'x'? I'm not quite clear on this behavior.

Comment: There are a number of problems here. What is `Object`? It must be overriding `do_something`, and it apparently tries to pass arguments to `super().__init__` itself once called, because nothing in the code you show does.

Comment: @chepner - I updated the post. *Object* (was) a parent class that does not override *do_something*. Its the behavior around super with Mixins that I am not clear on

Comment: The mixins aren't an issue. They don't override `__init__`, so `Test.__init__` goes directly to `ParentClass.__init__` via `super`.

Answer (score -1):

Order of operations ended up being the issue here. I needed to add the mixins after so

```
class Test(Mixin1, Mixin2, ParentClass):
```

goes too

```
class Test(ParentClass, Mixin1, Mixin2):
```

Comment: This answer (and the question along with it) is useless to the wider Stack Overflow community without disclosing what part of `ParentClass`'s definition made the order relevant.